# How can I put these dietary icons on the right side of screen on VStack

Tags: swiftui

I tried this code, following a tutorial:

```
HStack {
        Image(item.thumbnailImage)
            .clipShape(Circle())
            .overlay(Circle().stroke(.gray, lineWidth: 2))
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
       Spacer()
            
            ForEach(item.restrictions, id: \.self) { restriction in
                Text(restriction)
                    .font(.caption)
                    .fontWeight(.black)
                    .padding(5)
                    .background(colors [restriction, default: .black])
                    .clipShape(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/Circle()/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
            
            
            Text(item.name)
                .font(.headline)
            Text("$\(item.price)")
            }
```

I want to get a result like so:

[image: What i expect to]

But instead it looks like this:

[image: What i made]

The dietary icons should appear on the right-hand side of the text, but instead they appear above the text, one per line.

I thought that putting `Spacer()` in front of `ForEach(item.restrictions, id: \.self {`  should fix the problem, but it doesn't. What is wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Line 5 should read HStack not VStack if I had to take a guess

Comment: And for loop needs to come after the Texts if you want to stay true to the design

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your design is sorted in the wrong order. It should be in the same `HStack` as in your code. However, you have to change the order to get the expectation result. Here are steps: unembed `ForEach` and wrap it inside HStack, also wrap name & price inside VStack, then swap to VStack of name and price.

```swift
HStack {
    Image(item.thumbnailImage)
        .clipShape(Circle())
        .overlay(Circle().stroke(.gray, lineWidth: 2))
    
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Text(item.name)
            .font(.headline)
        Text("$\(item.price)")
    }
    
    HStack(alignment: .center) {
        ForEach(item.restrictions, id: \.self) { restriction in
            Text(restriction)
                .font(.caption)
                .fontWeight(.black)
                .padding(5)
                .background(colors [restriction, default: .black])
                .clipShape(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/Circle()/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
    }
}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: @SeokWonKang Could you mind if you tick it as the correct answer?